How the google sheet ui is made?
Today i have used it (i normally avoid apps which requires siginging in ) . I have noticed, its fast compared to the others of similiar kind yet It have the "all directional " scrolling and also zooming in and out.
My question is, how is all these possible (concrete information & code to build something like this)?
So i used to use a app,  it was and is simple and good . It feels somewhat even better than google sheet - cpu usage and resouce wise( if this contributes in a lighter feeling) . Anyway, It lacked few things i needed , thus since last few weeks im trying to create a ui like excel table. First i tried to create one in compose but it was utter failure. Horrible & unusable either  the vertical or the horizontal scrolling.
Then tried xml way. I didn't knew much but it took some time and I did created a prototype ui.

No "all directional" scrolling.

With edittexts as cell

No zooming in and out ( one of the reason I am trying)


Result- Performance horrible , unusable.
Then tried with textView . This time it's much much much better.
However, the problem is the adapter( well probably). To set/modify each cells text, I used a dialog with "ok" button to take input.
Now with this method, the cell's text is not updated immediately after clicking the okay button of the  dialog . There is a quite a delay which  is quite visible,  and an eyesore. Unlike what i saw today in the Google sheet app which can immediately reflects what your are writing in the cell letter by letter.
Used  both
notifyItemChanged(position)

And view model with barely anything in the adapter.
I'm pretty sure they are using some kind of tricks in ggle aheet. Since they first make me click the cell and then again make me click the edittext/inputfield , which is a bit annoying.
Regarding "all directional scrolling" and zooming - Previously , I only used this  in ggl maps . When i searched about it recently to apply to my cell based able ui my search results yielded really old results which I don't understand , honestly.
Since ggle maps been around for ages, is there anything easy out there to apply this behavioural properties to my table ui?
[Lastly, Ui. As I need to add new view or viewGroup to the  table screen , the time needed  for the ui appear is   increasing . Currently ,   If a table have 10 around cells, the table ui appears immediately but if the table have 30cells , mostly even empty, on average it's taking 4 seconds for the table ui to appear. ]
Anyway, anything concrete would be much appreciated. Wish you all good day.
